# Upload image to Mysql Database using android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hii i trying to upload a image to the Mysql database, and the image had been uploaded but i not sure whether I doing it correct or not.

Here is my code

```
public void onClick(View v) {

String name = ""+etName.getText().toString();
            String age = ""+etAge.getText().toString();

           String email = ""+etEmail.getText().toString();

           String img_str = ""+etImage.getImageAlpha();



           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_insert", img_str));
```

Am I doing it correctly for this part? `String img_str = ""+etImage.getImageAlpha();`

Comment: Which MySQL? Where is the image? It is not clear neither what are you trying to achieve nor how. I only see objects being added to an array.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to implement an IntentService and notify status with broadcast intents. please checkout complete code from github

https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service